# Dagger 2: use Component.Builder in a component with multiple modules dependencies

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, builder, dagger

I can't understand how properly inject Context when I have a component with multiple modules dependencies and I want use Component.Builder annotation.

I have an application module:

```
@Module  
public class ApplicationModule {
    @Provides
    public AppDatabase provideDatabase(Context context){
        return AppDatabase.getInstance(context);
    }  
}
```

And here is my ApplicationComponent where I used the Component.Builder in order to provide the context at the dependency graph:

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules =  { ApplicationModule.class } )
public interface ApplicationComponent {
   void inject(MainFragment mainFragment);

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder {
        @BindsInstance
        Builder context(Context context);

        ApplicationComponent build();
    }
}
```

From my custom application I use the following code in order to provide the context:

```
appComponent = DaggerApplicationComponent.builder().context(getApplicationContext()).build();
```

Then I have another Dagger module, used for providing my ViewModelsFactory: 
ViewModelModule

```
@Module
public class ViewModelModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public MainFragmentViewModelFactory provideMainFragmentViewModelFactory(IVehicleProvider vehicleProvider, IPaymentProvider paymentProvider, IBackgroundOperationResponse response){
        return new MainFragmentViewModelFactory(vehicleProvider, paymentProvider, response);
    }
}
```

And the relative ViewModelComponent, where I used again the Component.Builder and as you can see I have three modules here: ViewModelModule, ApplicationModule and ProviderModule

```
@Singleton
@Component( modules = { ViewModelModule.class, ApplicationModule.class, ProviderModule.class })
public interface ViewModelComponent {
    MainFragmentViewModelFactory getMainFragmentViewModelFactory();

    @Component.Builder
    interface Builder{
        @BindsInstance
        Builder context(Context context);

        @BindsInstance
        Builder response(IBackgroundOperationResponse response);

        ViewModelComponent build();
    }
}
```

Finally, since MainFragmentViewModelFactory requires IVehicleProvider and IPaymentProvider, I have another module:
ProviderModule

```
@Module
public abstract class ProviderModule {

    @Singleton
    @Binds
    abstract IVehicleProvider bindVehicleProvider(VehicleProvider vehicleProvider);

    @Singleton
    @Binds
    abstract IPaymentProvider bindPaymentProvider(PaymentProvider paymentProvider);
}
```

The followings are the constructors of PaymentProvider and VehicleProvider:

```
@Inject
public PaymentProvider(AppDatabase db){
    this.db = db;
}

@Inject
public VehicleProvider(AppDatabase db){
    this.db = db;
}
```

They require an AppDatabase which is provided on ApplicationModule class. AppDatabase requires a Context which is again provided in the ApplicationComponent using the Component.Builder

This code works properly, when I need to use mainFragmentViewModelFactory I just call

```
mainFragmentViewModelFactory = DaggerViewModelComponent
                .builder()
                .context(context)
                .response(this)
                .build()
                .getMainFragmentViewModelFactory();
```

However, I'm not sure I did the correct steps since in the ViewModelModule I requested again a Context dependency, but is already provided in the ApplicationModule. Have I done the correct steps? Instead of create again a BindsInstance Context in the ViewModelComponent can I use the one privided in ApplicationModule?

Comment: Usually you'd either use `@Subcomponent` or component dependencies, but you created two separate `@Singleton` components. If they both share the same lifecycle, then they should be merged, otherwise you should put them in relation (subcomponent, or component dependency) and use a different scope on one of them.

Comment: @David Medenjak, I'm not sure I understood what you said. Yes they are both Singleton since I don't need to create every time a new instance. I'm pretty new in Dagger, and I don't know exactly what do you mean with "subcomponent" and "component dependency".

Comment: Ok finally I understood what you wrote. I missed the Component dependencies. Now I declared a new Scope for ViewModelComponent and then I added ApplicationComponent to dependency of ViewModelComponent. Then in the builder I added a setter method for the ApplicationComponent and that's all. Now ViewModelComponent works without I need to set again the context, it uses the one exposed by ApplicationComponent. This video helped me a lot to understand Scope and Component dependency: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V-CF0BGA-3w&list=PLrnPJCHvNZuA2ioi4soDZKz8euUQnJW65&index=11